# Setting a static variable in a run () method in java

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, concurrent-programming

I have a static variable which I would like to set in a run() method. I have the following:

```
public class Test{
   public static int temp;
   public static void main(String [] args)
     {
         update();
         System.out.println("This is the content of temp"+temp);
     }
   public static void update()
    {
        (new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          // do some stuff
                   Test.temp=15;
       }}).start();
    }
```

I would like the content of temp to be updated to 15; but when I print it in the main function, it shows 0. How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Threads working concurrently so you should wait until your new thread finishes:

```
public class Test{
   public static int temp;
   public static void main(String [] args) {
      update().join(); //we wait until new thread finishes
      System.out.println("This is the content of temp"+temp);
   }

   public static Thread update() {
       Thread t = new Thread() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
             // do some stuff
             Test.temp=15;
          }
       };
       t.start();
       return t;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to understand how Thread works.

I will show you two pieces of code here first is to understand, variables that are initialized inside the thread takes take time to update until the thread is finished.

```
public class Num {

    public static int temp;
       public static void main(String [] args) throws InterruptedException
         {
            update();

             System.out.println("This is the content of temp"+Num.temp);//This will print before temp=15 is updated
         }
       public static void update()
        {
            (new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              // do some stuff
                       Num.temp=15;   
                       System.out.println("Value of temp:"+Num.temp);//This statement prints after
           }}).start();
        }
}
```

It Prints the following:

```
This is the content of temp0
Value of temp:15
```

Second one shows, if you wait for a small amount time(Thread.sleep(10)) after the thread is executed, the value gets updated:

```
public class Num {

    public static int temp;
       public static void main(String [] args) throws InterruptedException
         {
            update();
            Thread.sleep(10);
             System.out.println("This is the content of temp"+Num.temp);//This will print correct value now
         }
       public static void update()
        {
            (new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              // do some stuff
                       Num.temp=15;                      
           }}).start();
        }
}
```

But here I would suggest the same method as Philip did. Just add `throws InterruptedException` in main function